# How to change timezone on docker private registry running container?

Tags: docker, timezone, registry

How can I change timezone/time on my **running** docker **private registry** container

Host OS: CentOS 7 
Docker Version:

```
Server:
Version:      17.09.0-ce
API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:   go1.8.3
Git commit:   afdb6d4
Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Experimental: false
```

Docker registry image: `registry:2 ID: a07e3f32a779`

Tried execute on container:

    `export TZ=Europe/Warsaw
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone`

but without any result for real time.

Same solution works on another containers without any problems.

Any Ideas?

**Edit:**

Recreated container with compose like this:

```
apache:                                                           
  image: "httpd:2.4"                                              
  hostname: deleted                                    
  restart: always                                                 
  environment:                                                    
    - TZ=Europe/Warsaw                                            
  ports:                                                          
    - 5043:5043                                                   
  links:                                                          
    - registry:registry                                           
  volumes:                                                        
    - /opt/docker-registry-bundle/auth:/usr/local/apache2/conf    
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro                              

registry:                                                         
  image: registry:2                                               
  restart: always                                                 
  environment:                                                    
    - TZ=Europe/Warsaw                                            
  ports:                                                          
    - 127.0.0.1:5000:5000                                         
  volumes:                                                        
    - /opt/docker-registry-bundle/registry-data:/var/lib/registry 
    - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
```

On apache container time is ok.
On registry container still doesn't work.

Comment: is the single qoutes at the end of /etc/timezone' is typo error?

Comment: I accidentally pressed single quote button here.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work when executed inside container:

```
echo "Europe/Warsaw" > /etc/timezone
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata`

Comment: Is there any error? Also try restarting the container.

Comment: Chceck my edit note, recreated container with no effect. after execute command: `sh: dpkg-reconfigure: not found`

Comment: registry:2 image uses alpine base image because of that dpkg command is missing, refer below link which explains how to change timezone in alpine based images.
https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2015/10/31/time-in-docker-containers/  ( see Alpine Linux section )

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** from sanath

> registry:2 image uses alpine base image because of that dpkg command
>   is missing, refer below link which explains how to change timezone in
>   alpine based images.
>   ivankrizsan.se/2015/10/31/time-in-docker-containers ( see Alpine Linux
>   section )